# On typing arrow in VS code appears tag </P>

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

On typing arrow appears `</P>` tag. What is the reason of it? I'm using Visual Studio Code with extensions.

```
useEffect(() => </P>, []);
```

Comment: I think I remember something like this being brought up before, and that someone said that it's a bug that has since been fixed... maybe. Is your VSCode up to date?

Comment: _"on typing arrow"_ -- which key(s) do you press can you specify? Maybe its because of a misconfigured key binding if not a bug.

Comment: In case if your VSCode is up to date, then you mentioned VS code with extensions. So adding the list/screenshot of installed extensions would help.

Comment: disable all extensions, and enable one by one to see who is the culprit